# How to precisely place a cropped and resized image with PDFlib?

Tags: php, image, crop, pdflib

Wrestled with this for a couple of hours and just can't figure out how PDFlib works. I have this image that we'll say has the size of 1000 x 300 pixels:

[image]

Now I want to place a part of the image into a box of 20 x 12 millimeters (at 300 dpi). The resizing must be such that if no cropping were done the image would take up 70 x 21 mm on the page. 3 mm of the image must be cropped away from the top, and 2 mm cropped away from the left side.

[image]

The examples and documentation are too weak for me to understand exactly how the parameters for `fit_image()` work. How do I accomplish this?

*Note: I'm doing this in PHP but I guess the main concern is what parameters PDFlib needs, which is language independent.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps required to get this solved, but of course it's easily possible. Your question contains various task which must be solved:

1. scale down the input image to a given area
2. clip this scaled down image
3. place the image scaled and clipped to a given position. (this was not exactly clear from your question, so you might adjust the x/y parameters of the fit_image() depending to your needs.

This is one way to solve it:

```php
# Load the image
$image = $p->load_image("auto", $imagefile, "");

# First we retrieve the dimension and the resolution for the loaded image
$imagewidth = $p->info_image($image, "imagewidth", "");
$imageheight = $p->info_image($image, "imageheight", "");
$dpix = $p->info_image($image, "resx", "");
$dpiy = $p->info_image($image, "resy", "");

# Calculate the scale factor, to fit the image to a width/height of 70 x 21 mm.
# Use a helper function to calculate the mm-values to the PDF points
$scalex = mm2pt(70) / $imagewidth; 
$scaley = mm2pt(21) / $imageheight; 

# For demonstrating the correct placing, fit the loaded image with a
# size of 70x21 mm with a light opacity (scaling it to this dimension
# might distort the image ratio) (final code would not include this)
$gstate = $p->create_gstate("opacityfill=.4");
$optlist = sprintf("gstate=%d scale {%f %f} dpi=72",
                $gstate, $scalex, $scaley);
$p->fit_image($image, mm2pt(10), mm2pt(250), $optlist);

# Use dpi=72 to ignore the internal DPI value and interpret each image 
# pixel without scaling.
# Now, specify the partial area with a matchbox clipping (remember that
# those values are the positions within the 70x21, and y goes from bottom to top)
$optlist = sprintf("scale {%f %f} matchbox={clipping={%f %f %f %f}} dpi=72", 
                    $scalex, $scaley, mm2pt(2)/$scalex, mm2pt(6)/$scaley, 
                    mm2pt(22)/$scalex, mm2pt(18)/$scaley);

# Set the reference point, so the origin of the clipped image will be the 
# same as for the original image
$p->fit_image($image, mm2pt(10)+mm2pt(2), mm2pt(250)+mm2pt(6), $optlist);

function mm2pt($mm){
    return $mm*2.83465;
}
```

so when using this code and one of the PDFlib sample Images to place the partially image on top of the original image, I get the following output:
[image]

Comment: I don't see where you set the 3 mm above the image and the width/height of 20 and 12 mm? I guess it's pretty much the numbers for the clipping box I don't understand...

Comment: Figured it out now. The 3 mm is subtracted from the 21 mm, hence 18 as the last clipping value. The width of 20 mm is added to the left of the image, hence 22 as the 3rd clipping value. The height of 12 mm is the difference between the 2nd and last clipping value.

Comment: well, the reference point of the image is the lower left corner. From there you have to do the calculation.